# Is coroutineScope just like block function in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm learning CoroutineScope, I know `launch{ }` will not block work in Code A, so I get the Result A as I expected.

I think I should get Result B2 when I run Code B, but I get Result B1, why?

It seems that the `coroutineScope` block the programm to run until it finished, right? So I write Code C to verify my ideas, I get Result C just like `coroutineScope` block the program.

**Code A**

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() = runBlocking { 
    launch { 
        delay(200L)
        println("Task from runBlocking")
    }  
       
    println("Coroutine scope is over") 
}
```

**Result A**

```
Coroutine scope is over
Task from runBlocking
```

**Code B**

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() = runBlocking { 
    launch { 
        delay(200L)
        println("Task from runBlocking")
    }
    
    coroutineScope { 
        launch {
            delay(500L) 
            println("Task from nested launch")
        }
    
        delay(100L)
        println("Task from coroutine scope") 
    }
    
    println("Coroutine scope is over") 
}
```

**Result B1**

```
Task from coroutine scope
Task from runBlocking
Task from nested launch
Coroutine scope is over
```

**Result B2**

```
Coroutine scope is over
Task from coroutine scope
Task from runBlocking
Task from nested launch
```

**Code C**

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() = runBlocking { 
    coroutineScope { 
        launch {
            delay(500L) 
            println("Task from nested launch")
        }
    
        delay(100L)
        println("Task from coroutine scope") 
    }
        
    launch { 
        delay(200L)
        println("Task from runBlocking")
    }   
    
    println("Coroutine scope is over") 
}
```

**Result C**

```
Task from coroutine scope
Task from nested launch
Coroutine scope is over
Task from runBlocking
```

Comment: A CoroutineScope defines a lifecycle, a lifetime, for Coroutines that are built and launched from it. It blocks nothing.

Comment: @bylazy the question isn't about `CoroutineScope` but `coroutineScope`.